# Laying out Tables in Interface Builder

Tags: ios, uitableview

Is it possible to fill UITableViews in InterfaceBuilder with some sample data? Because I know that I have 4 Entries in this table, but want to layout this to a specific edge. But as I don't know the exact size of the final Table (only when Debugging I can see the data) I can not layout them.

Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

BR

Answer (score 0):

Filling `UITableView` with data can be from the `UITableViewDataSource` protocol, so from interface builder as my understood you cant.

You can always layout the table after the data is loaded by using: `tableview.frame = ...`

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a job for `UITableView` static cells, which are available in iOS 5 and above, and allow you to enter data into UITableViewCells directly in IB. Take a look at [Ray Wenderlich's tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5191/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-2) which covers this topic (scroll down to the "Static Cells" section).